Finding correlation Between $Z$ and $Y$ Given $\mathrm{Z} | \mathrm{X} = x \sim N(x, \kappa^2)$ and $(\mathrm{X}, \mathrm{Y}) \sim N$
Is it possible to determine the correlation between Z and Y from the following information?
Assume that $\mathrm{Z} | \mathrm{X} = x \sim N(x, \kappa^2)$ and that $\mathrm{X}$ and $\mathrm{Y}$ are jointly normally distributed with correlation $\rho$.
To calculate the correlation $\rho'$ between $\mathrm{X}$ and $\mathrm{Y}$, we would need their joint distribution, correct? How can I find that?

You mean $\rho'$ between $Z$ and $Y$ in the last paragraph, right?

Yes that is correct.

There is no way to determine the correlation between $Y$ and $Z$. Here is a counterexample.
Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent identically distributed $N(0,\kappa^2)$. On one hand, I can define $Z$ independent of $Y$ by letting $Z \mid X = x $ follow $N(x, \kappa^2)$ so that $Z$ and $Y$ have zero correlation. On the other hand, I can put $Z = X + Y$. When $X=x$ is observed, $Z$ follows $N(x, \kappa^2)$ and clearly it has nonzero correlation with $Y$.
We can also reason this through. By simple manipulations, we know that $Z$ is also normally distributed and $(X,Y,Z)$ can be seen as jointly normal. If we look at its covariance matrix :
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_X^2 & \sigma_X \sigma_Y\rho & a \\
\sigma_X \sigma_Y\rho & \sigma_Y^2 & b \\
a & b & \sigma_Z^2 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Here $a$ is a known constant that can be calculated from the distribution $Z \mid X=x$. However, there is no way to know $b$. It could be any number such that the matrix is positive definite.

Update : in the counterexample, if $W$ is a random variable with $N(0, \kappa^2)$ distribution, independent of $X$, has correlation $\rho'$ with $Y$, setting $Z = X + W$ would yield a correlation of $\rho'$ to $Y$ as well. In other words, $Z$ and $Y$ really can have any correlation you want.

Given all values except $\rho'$ in $$\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_X^2 & \sigma_X \sigma_Y\rho & \sigma_X^2 \
\sigma_X \sigma_Y\rho & \sigma_Y^2 & \rho'\sigma_Y\sqrt{\sigma_X^2+k^2} \
\sigma_X^2 & \rho'\sigma_Y\sqrt{\sigma_X^2+k^2} & \sigma_X^2+k^2
\end{bmatrix},$$
what values $\rho'$ are feasible to make it non-negative definite?

I have updated the post. The correlation of $Z$ and $Y$ can really be anything you want.

If other parameters are free to be chosen, we can get any $|\rho'|\leq1$. But for given values of other parameters, $\rho'$ has to be restricted. For example, if we let $\sigma_X^2=\sigma_Y^2=\kappa^2=1$ and $\rho=0$, then $|\rho'|\leq \frac1{\sqrt{2}}$.

Thanks, this is a very nice answer. I might have been a bit unclear, but I meant to assume the correlation $\rho$ between $\mathrm{X}$ and $\mathrm{Y}$ to be nonzero. This makes your first example non-applicable. As for the example from the update, I cannot quickly tell what the correlation between $Z$ and $Y$ would be if we also assume that $X$ has correlation $\rho \neq 0 $ with $Y$.
